# StringBuilder - read N characters

Tags: c#, string, performance, substring

I'm dealing with HUGE strings (file of 100MB - text). The file text is stored in StringBuilder.

From some reason, I'm need to change the encoding of this text, Can't expect this before, From CURRENT-Encoding to NEW-Encoding. So, I'm need to use the

```
Encoding.Convert(...)
```

function. Since this file is HUGH, I'm want to break it to parts. For example, 1024 characters each time. Breaking the StringBuilder to sub strings is seems like a problem to me, since I'm don't want to use the

```
.ToString()
```

function (**Performance reason**).

How do you recommend me to do this, without bring the whole text to one single string?

Comment: You could use a [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx).

Comment: What benefit do you see performance-wise in splitting the string in chunks? You still need to convert the whole string, right?

Comment: What kind of encodings are you talking about? Can the characters have variable lengths (e.g UTF-8 with characters outside ASCII or UTF-16 with characters outside BMP)?

Answer (score 3):

Just use a StreamReader so you can stream the file (as opposed to entirely reading it at once) and write the characters it reads back to your new file using the specified encoding:

```
string sourcePath = "...";
string destinationPath = "...";
Encoding sourceEncoding = Encoding.UTF16;
Encoding destinationEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

char[] readBuffer = new char[1024];
int bytesRead;

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(destinationPath, false, destinationEncoding))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourcePath, sourceEncoding))
    {
        while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also specify the source encoding?

Comment: @svick you're right, thanks, fixed. The docs claim the [`StreamReader(string)` constructor defaults to UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx), I thought it read the BOM and did some guessing - guess I'm wrong.

Comment: It seems that's what [`StreamReader(string path, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y86s1a9) is for. Though you can't always rely on BOM, especially with legacy non-Unicode encodings.

Comment: And it looks like the docs are wrong. [According to the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#183), `new StreamReader(path)` chains to `new StreamReader(path, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true)`.